# How to get the width of the largest-area rectangle that contains only black pixels in a binarized image

Tags: image-processing

The following image is only for illustration and I am not sure if that is really the largest-area rectangle with only black pixels.

[image]

So the largest-area rectangle is ***possibly*** this (in Red):
[image]

The required is to get its width (that is between the Blue lines), which is (in Yellow):
[image]

---

So simply the required is the width of the largest-area rectangle that contains only black pixels.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is an example of the [largest empty rectangle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_empty_rectangle). There are some Mathematica implementations on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161332/find-the-largest-rectangular-block-satisfying-some-condition-without-iterating-e).

Comment: @Domen So not possible yet?

Comment: Is there some reason why there appears to be a restriction that a rectangle can't be rotated by some angle?

Comment: @JimB There is a reason for this restriction. The actual measurement which usually I do manually by (Paint) software is the horizontal distance (this is related to lab analysis research and difficult to explain in a comment)(The white points in original post represent chemical substance). However, if you can provide a code for the largest-area rectangle (even rotated), it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

This is not a scalable solution and thus not really an answer to the question, but I want to demonstrate that you can solve this kind of a problem quite literally by just phrasing the problem statement in Mathematica:

```
With[{
  reg = Rectangle[],
  sol = Rectangle[{x0, y0}, {x1, y1}]},
 With[{pts = Point@RandomPoint[reg, 8]},
  Graphics[
    {Blue, sol,
     PointSize@Large, Red, pts,
     FaceForm@None, EdgeForm@Black, reg}] /.
   Last@Quiet@Maximize[
      {Area@sol,
       x0 < x1 && y0 < y1 &&
        RegionWithin[reg, sol] &&
        RegionDisjoint[sol, pts]},
      {x0, y0, x1, y1}]]]
```

[image]

Basically here we ask for maximisation of the area of the rectangle `sol` so that it lies within the region `reg`, while it has no overlap with any of the points in `pts`. (Pedantically, in this case some of the points in `pts` lie in the region boundary of `sol`.)

The limiting factor here is the number of points - run times explode already around 10. There are surely drastically more efficient algorithms for the task...

Answer (score 6):

**=== UPDATED ANSWER ===**

The method below works for "white dots" and larger white areas. The rectangles are grown one row of pixels at a time.

```
(* binarize image *)
idb = ImageData[Binarize@image];

(* split image to group together sequences of 0s or 1s *)

sp = Split[#] & /@ idb;

(* Process each row to replace sequences with Intervals, keeping only the 0s and their positions *)
intervals = {};
r = 1;
While[r <= Length[sp],
 rintervals = {};
 i = 1;
 If[#[[1]] == 0, 
    AppendTo[rintervals, Interval[{i, i + Length[#] - 1}]]; 
    i = i + Length[#], i = i + Length[#]] & /@ sp[[r]];
 AppendTo[intervals, IntervalUnion @@ rintervals];
 r++;
 ]

(* We process each row of Intervals as a starting row for a potential \
rectangle, having the width of an interval on that row. We then do \
successive IntervalIntersection with all the following rows, using \
NestList. This normally results in breaking down intervals into \
smaller intervals on these subsequent rows and therefore smaller \
possible rectangles. *)
finalIntervals = {};
rectRowCount = 1;
While[rectRowCount <= Length[intervals],
 i = 1;
 intersectionRows = Drop[intervals, rectRowCount];
 AppendTo[finalIntervals, 
  rectRowCount -> 
   NestList[IntervalIntersection[#, intersectionRows[[i++]]] &, 
    intervals[[rectRowCount]], Length[intersectionRows]]];
 rectRowCount++;
 ]

(* finalIntervals now contains the required information to determine \
where the largest rectangle will be *)
largestArea = 0;
rectRowCount = 1;
While[rectRowCount <= Length[finalIntervals],
  inter = 1;
  While[inter <= Length[finalIntervals[[rectRowCount]][[2]]],
   intervalList = List @@ finalIntervals[[rectRowCount]][[2]][[inter]];
   index = 1;
   While[index <= Length[intervalList],
    area = 
     inter*(intervalList[[index]][[2]] - intervalList[[index]][[1]]);
    If[area > largestArea, largestArea = area;
     rectData = <|"Area" -> largestArea, 
       "Rectangle" -> {{intervalList[[index]][[2]], 
          ImageDimensions[image][[2]] - (rectRowCount + inter) + 
           1}, {intervalList[[index]][[1]], 
          ImageDimensions[image][[2]] - rectRowCount + 1}}, 
       "Width" -> 
        Abs[
         intervalList[[index]][[2]] - 
          intervalList[[index]][[1]]]|>
     ];
    
    index++;
    ];
   inter++;
   ];
  rectRowCount++;
  ];

rectData

(*
<|"Area" -> 91680, "Rectangle" -> {{383, 25}, {1, 265}}, 
 "Width" -> 382|>
*)
```

Here are a few pictures. Note that the original "stars in the sky" image gives a different rectangle. The one crossing the entire screen comes a close second.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**===== PREVIOUS ANSWER BELOW =====**

Here are some experimental results. Not sure if it has some validity... it gets very confusing after a while.

```
(* ImageCorners can retrieve white dot positions on a black background \
*)
pts = ImageCorners[image];

(* highlighted points for visuals *)
hpts = HighlightImage[image, pts]

(* To facilitate working with rectangles, if some points are aligned \
on the x or y coordinate, all points will be very slightly nudged *)
While[! DuplicateFreeQ[
    pts, (#1[[1]] == #2[[1]] || #1[[2]] == #2[[2]] ) &],
  ptsMod = RandomReal[{-0.0001, 0.0001}] + # & /@ pts;
  pts = ptsMod;
  ];
```

[image]

Rectangles are defined by two opposite corners (x1,y1) and (x2,y2), but there are different ways to use our `pts` to find these two corners:

1. Select two points in pts to be the two corners.
2. Select one point in pts to be a corner {x1,y1} and two points in pts where virtual lines (horizontal and vertical) through these points intersect to give possible {x2,y2}.
3. No point in pts is a corner. We must deal with four points in pts with lines intersecting to form possible {x2,y2}.

The following attemps the three approaches and finds the maximum rectangle area for each. The winner will be the rect with the largest area overall. With this method, the image border is ignored. All sides of a rectangle are aligned with real or virtual lines crossing a point in `pts`.

```
(* Selection of two points assigned to corners *)

sub2 = Subsets[pts, {2}];
rects2 = 
  Select[sub2, 
   RegionDisjoint[BoundingRegion[#, "MinRectangle"], 
     Point@DeleteCases[pts, #[[1]] | #[[2]]]] &];
rect2Max = Flatten[MaximalBy[rects2, Area[Rectangle @@ #] &], 1];
area2 = Area[Rectangle @@ rect2Max];
Show[hpts, Graphics[Rectangle @@ rect2Max], 
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[Style[
    "Area = " ~~ ToString[ area2] ~~ "\nWidth = " ~~ 
     ToString[Abs[rect2Max[[2]][[1]] - rect2Max[[1]][[1]]]], 
    White], (rect2Max[[1]] + rect2Max[[2]])/2]]
```

[image]

For the second method, I show the first and second largest rectangle. Areas are relatively close.

```
(* Selection of three points, one of which assigned to a corner *)

sub3 = Subsets[pts, {3}];
sub3Mod = Flatten[
   {{#[[1]], {#[[2]][[1]], #[[3]][[2]]}},
      {#[[1]], {#[[3]][[1]], #[[2]][[2]]}},
      {#[[2]], {#[[1]][[1]], #[[3]][[2]]}},
      {#[[2]], {#[[3]][[1]], #[[1]][[2]]}},
      {#[[3]], {#[[2]][[1]], #[[1]][[2]]}},
      {#[[3]], {#[[1]][[1]], #[[2]][[2]]}}} & /@ sub3, 1];
rects3 = 
  Select[sub3Mod, 
   RegionDisjoint[BoundingRegion[#, "MinRectangle"], 
     Point@(DeleteCases[
        pts, #[[1]] | {#[[2]][[1]], _} | {_, #[[2]][[2]]}])] &];
rect3Max = MaximalBy[rects3, Area[Rectangle @@ #] &, 2][[1]];
area3 = Area[Rectangle @@ rect3Max];
Show[hpts, Graphics[Rectangle @@ rect3Max], 
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[Style[
    "Area = " ~~ ToString[ area3] ~~ "\nWidth = " ~~ 
     ToString[Abs[rect3Max[[2]][[1]] - rect3Max[[1]][[1]]]], 
    White], (rect3Max[[1]] + rect3Max[[2]])/2]]

rect3Max2 = MaximalBy[rects3, Area[Rectangle @@ #] &, 2][[2]];
area3b = Area[Rectangle @@ rect3Max2];
Show[hpts, Graphics[Rectangle @@ rect3Max2], 
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[Style[
    "Area = " ~~ ToString[ area3b] ~~ "\nWidth = " ~~ 
     ToString[Abs[rect3Max2[[2]][[1]] - rect3Max2[[1]][[1]]]], 
    White], (rect3Max2[[1]] + rect3Max2[[2]])/2]]
```

[image]

[image]

```
(* Selection of four points none of which assigned to a corner *)

sub4 = Subsets[pts, {4}];
sub4Mod = Flatten[
   {
      {{#[[1]][[1]], #[[2]][[2]]}, {#[[3]][[1]], #[[4]][[2]]}},
      {{#[[2]][[1]], #[[1]][[2]]}, {#[[3]][[1]], #[[4]][[2]]}},
      {{#[[1]][[1]], #[[2]][[2]]}, {#[[4]][[1]], #[[3]][[2]]}},
      {{#[[1]][[1]], #[[1]][[2]]}, {#[[3]][[1]], #[[4]][[2]]}},
      
      {{#[[1]][[1]], #[[3]][[2]]}, {#[[2]][[1]], #[[4]][[2]]}},
      {{#[[3]][[1]], #[[1]][[2]]}, {#[[2]][[1]], #[[4]][[2]]}},
      {{#[[1]][[1]], #[[3]][[2]]}, {#[[4]][[1]], #[[2]][[2]]}},
      {{#[[3]][[1]], #[[1]][[2]]}, {#[[2]][[1]], #[[4]][[2]]}},
      
      {{#[[1]][[1]], #[[4]][[2]]}, {#[[3]][[1]], #[[2]][[2]]}},
      {{#[[4]][[1]], #[[1]][[2]]}, {#[[3]][[1]], #[[2]][[2]]}},
      {{#[[1]][[1]], #[[4]][[2]]}, {#[[2]][[1]], #[[3]][[2]]}},
      {{#[[4]][[1]], #[[1]][[2]]}, {#[[2]][[1]], #[[3]][[2]]}}
      
      } & /@ sub4, 1];
rects4 = 
  Select[sub4Mod, 
   RegionDisjoint[BoundingRegion[#, "MinRectangle"], 
     Point@
      DeleteCases[
       pts, #[[1]] | {#[[2]][[1]], _} | {_, #[[2]][[2]]}]] &];
rect4Max = Flatten[MaximalBy[rects4, Area[Rectangle @@ #] &], 1];
area4 = Area[Rectangle @@ rect4Max];
Show[hpts, Graphics[Rectangle @@ rect4Max], 
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[Style[
    "Area = " ~~ ToString[ area4] ~~ "\nWidth = " ~~ 
     ToString[Abs[rect4Max[[2]][[1]] - rect4Max[[1]][[1]]]], 
    White], (rect4Max[[1]] + rect4Max[[2]])/2]]
```

[image]

Comment: Great, this is "almost" what I am looking for. However, it needs to be improved. I put a binarized image but it returned something I do not know. Original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2Q3g.jpg . It returned: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKps6.png . Which is not the larges-area rectangle containing only black pixels, but containing white pixels. I believe you can help me fixing it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Indeed this approach would only work for "dots" on a black background, not for larger white shapes. Dots are picked up based on being contiguous with black areas (it picks up dots on borders). All areas ouside the dots are then considered black in the code.

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari You can use `ComponentMeasurements[img, "IntensityCentroid"]` to find the coordinates of the "dots".

Comment: @Hussain-Alquatari Contrary to my first answer, the new and better approach I just posted extends the rectangles to the edges of the image. But I note that in the example you gave in the question your red rectangle does not extend to the left edge. Should virtual edges delimited by white pixels closest to edges be used? If so, then the first step in my new approach would be to define this new virtual  boder and use it as if it was the border of the image.

Answer (score 6):

**Disclaimer:**  Below I have used (stolen?) a function and ideas from the answer of @Jean-Pierre of which I don't fully understand. (If integer pixel positions are desired, why does `ImageCorners` return values that aren't integers?)

The approach below finds all of the horizontal values (including the minimum and maximum indices of the image's pixel positions.  Any rectangle not including a white point must be between 2 of those horizontal values.  For any 2 of those horizontal values all of the vertical positions of the points between those two horizontal values are found.  The largest difference between any two successive vertical values will be the largest rectangle not containing any white pixels.  This is repeated for all possible pairs of horizontal values.

```
maxArea[img_] := 
 Module[{pts, width, height, w, pairs, maxStats, s, diffs, dmax, 
   index, area, rectWidth, rectHeight},
  
  (* Select points and sort by second part of each element *)
  pts = Sort[ImageCorners[img], #1[[2]] < #2[[2]] &];
  
  (* Dimensions of image *)
  {width, height} = ImageDimensions[img];
  
  (* Get all of the horizontal values including the two border points *)
  w = DeleteDuplicates[Sort[Join[{0}, {width + 1}, pts[[All, 1]]]]];
  
  (* All possible pairs of horizontal points *)
  pairs = Subsets[w, {2}];
  maxStats = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
  Do[
   (* Select points with horizontal values between a each pair of potential 
      rectangle boundary points and include the lowermost and uppermost points
      just outside of the image boundary *)
   s = DeleteDuplicates[Join[{{0, 0}}, Select[pts, pairs[[i, 1]] < #[[1]] < pairs[[i, 2]] &],
     {{0, height + 1}}]];
   (* Find the largest vertical difference between two consecutive points *)
   diffs = Differences[s[[All, 2]]];
   dmax = Max[diffs];
   index = Position[diffs, dmax][[1, 1]]; (* Where the maximum difference occurs *)
   (* Calculate the area of the largest eligible rectangle between the current
      two left and right boundary points.  Subtract 1 for the width and height
      as I assume the area must not include any of the points in pnts *)
   area = (dmax - 1) (pairs[[i, 2]] - pairs[[i, 1]] - 1);  
   If[area > maxStats[[1]],
    (* Update summary *)
    rectWidth = pairs[[i, 2]] - pairs[[i, 1]] - 1;
    rectHeight = dmax - 1;
    maxStats = {area, rectWidth, rectHeight, pairs[[i, 1]], 
      pairs[[i, 2]], s[[index, 2]], s[[index + 1, 2]]}],
   {i, 1, Length[pairs]}];
  
  (* Return summaries *)
  {maxStats,
   TableForm[{maxStats}, 
    TableHeadings -> {None, {"Maximum\nArea", "\nWidth", "\nHeight", 
       "\nLeft", "\nRight", "\nBottom", "\nTop"}}],
   (* Plot results *)
   Show[ListPlot[{{1, 1}, {1, height}, {width, height}, {width, 
       0}, {0, 0}},
     PlotStyle -> LightGray, Joined -> True, 
     PlotRangeClipping -> False, Axes -> False,
     PlotRange -> {{-0.05 width, 1.05 width}, {-0.05 height, 
        1.05 height}}],
    ListPlot[pts, PlotRangeClipping -> False],
    RegionPlot[
     maxStats[[4]] + 1 <= x <= maxStats[[5]] - 1 && 
      maxStats[[6]] + 1 <= y <= maxStats[[7]] - 1,
     {x, 0, width + 1}, {y, 0, height + 1}, PlotPoints -> 100]]}
  ]
```

Now execute the function:

```
results = maxArea[image];
results[[2]]
```

[image: Summary results]

```
results[[3]]
```

[image: Points and largest rectangle not containing white dots]

Comment: Great! No stealing here. This is why posting incomplete answers may help. I knew the logic of the approach had to do with the order of the points horizontally and vertically (my first action was to sort the points both ways), but could not articulate that logic clearly, as you did.